# Cannot access Couchbase memcached buckets in Docker

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, memcached, couchbase

I'm unable to access buckets created as memcached when Couchbase is hosted in Docker. See my docker-compose below.
I can access the web client without problems.

Does anyone know if I need to map any other ports?

> NOTE: I'm able to access all type of buckets if Couchbase Server is installed on Windows.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  couchbase:
    container_name: couchbase
    image: couchbase:community-6.5.0
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/couchbase/var/:/opt/couchbase/var/
    networks:
      - back
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 8094:8094
      - 11209:11209
      - 11210:11210
      - 11211:11211
```

**Exception**

Recieves two exceptions on `cluster.OpenBucket(...)`:

- `Could not bootstrap with CCCP.`
- `Value does not fall within the expected range.`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend trying it with a local install (directly on Windows, for instance) just to confirm that it's a port issue

If you think it's a port issue, then you may want to have a look at the full list of ports that Couchbase uses: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html

For memcached alone, it looks like you have the right ports already (except 11207, which is for ssl), but you may want to try opening up some of the other points just to make sure (maybe 4369 or the 211xx ports?)

If that doesn't work, then maybe post a separate question with your .NET code. It could be something that's not port related at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try add to the extra ports. My code works with local install on Windows and it also works with Couchbase buckets on Docker. So I know that it is not my code.

Comment: I tried add a lot of ports, but with no luck. I'm starting to think that it could be a problem with their Docker image. I have written to Couchbase for help.